# scheme contract violation error

Tags: compiler-errors, scheme, racket

```
(define (real x) (car x))
(define (imag x) (cdr x))
(define (complex-sqrt x)
    (define (first a b) (sqrt (/ (+ a
                              (sqrt (+
                                     (* a a)
                                     (* b b))))
                           2)))
    (define (second a b) (sqrt (/ (+ (* -1 a)
                               (sqrt (+
                                      (* a a)
                                      (* b b))))
                            2)))
(cons (first (real x) (imag x)) (second (real x) (real y))))
(complex-sqrt '(2 3))
```

I keep getting an error that says "* contract violation: expected number" when it tries to evaluate (first a b) and (second a b). I'm not sure if this information is relevant, but the input will always be a list of 2 numbers.

Comment: Are you using `#lang racket` or one of the student languages?

Comment: I am using the R5RS language.

Comment: `(2 3)` is equal to `(cons 2 (cons 3 null))`. I think you mean to use `(cons 2 3)` as the input.

Comment: In your current code 'y' is unbound. I think 'real y' should be 'imag x'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included a complete example, so it's hard to say what goes wrong.
Maybe you are calling `complex-sqrt` with an argument of the wrong type?

This works for me:

```
#lang r5rs
(define (real x) (car x))
(define (imag x) (cdr x))
(define (complex-sqrt x)
  (define (first a b) (sqrt (/ (+ a
                                  (sqrt (+
                                         (* a a)
                                         (* b b))))
                               2)))
  (define (second a b) (sqrt (/ (+ (* -1 a)
                                   (sqrt (+
                                          (* a a)
                                          (* b b))))
                                2)))
  (cons (first  (real x) (imag x))
        (second (real x) (imag x))))

(display (complex-sqrt (cons 1 2)))
(newline)
```

Comment: It looks like the OP was attempting to pass `(list 1 2)` rather than a pair, judging from the last sentence of the question.

Comment: Sounds likely. Can you remember whether this is a SICP exercise?

Comment: @sara Then you need to change the definition of `imag` to `(define (imag x) (car (cdr x)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
(define (imag x) (cdr x))
```

to:

```
(define (imag x) (second x))
```

(This is built-in 'second' function and not your second function. It is equivalent to `(car (cdr lst))` or second item of list).

Then it works:

```
(complex-sqrt '(2 3))
; output:  '(1.6741492280355401 . 0.895977476129838)
```

`(cdr x)` is a list while `(second x)` is an item.

The original error in full mentions this clearly:

```
*: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: '(3)                     ; <<<<<< NOTE
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

Item and not list is needed for '*' function.

Also, you should not use 'first' and 'second' as your own function names since they are built in functions (to get first and second elements of any list). See [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=first#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._first%29%29).

The second last statement in your function:

```
(cons (first (real x) (imag x)) (second (real x) (real y))))
```

should be indented since it is part of complex-sqrt function. (Tip: to easily apply proper indentation to entire code in DrRacket, Select All and press tab.)

`(real y)` should be `(imag x)`

Comment: Shadowing in the lexical scope is OK but risky. Redefining globals in the report is only OK only if it's functionality still is the same as the report. Thus OPs `second` is not OK in the global namespace since it doesn't support pairs.